# Download.js is not working for pdf mimetype

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a requirement to download a file on clicking a link on Page. On button click, called a download js file from [HERE](http://danml.com/download.html).

But this is not working fine with mimetype application/pdf. Any help?

Can try [HERE](http://pagedemos.com/sxks39b72aqb/1) standalone demo for testing download.js.

```
download("hello world", "dlText.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want [JsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) which is dedicated to solve PDF stuff.

All you need to do is use `setText()` function

```js
 var doc = new jsPDF();
 doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
 doc.save('is_this_what_you_are_looking_for.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh. So when I follow this, I am getting the following error.   spdf.js:471 Error in function Object.: saveAs is not defined ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined at Object.<anonymous> (jspdf.js:962) at Object.__safeCallWrapper [as output] (jspdf.js:465) at Object.API.save (jspdf.js:2029) at Object.success (detail.js:287) at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2) at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2) at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4) at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no Javascript needed at all. **Solved it server side**. In case anyone looking for server side Java solution.

The controller worked without any js apis.

```
public static void downloadFile(
        final HttpServletResponse response,
        final String fileName,
        final String fileType,
        final byte[] decodedDocument) throws Exception {

    /* Set the file properties */
    if (fileType == null) {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    } else {
        response.setContentType(fileType);
    }
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    /* Convert bytes to stream of objects */
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedDocument);

    /*Download copying the content to destination file */
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `BLOB` data type, You need to change your code as,

```
download(new Blob(["hello world"]), "dlText.pdf", "application/pdf");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No. This is also not working. You can check on standalone url here. http://pagedemos.com/sxks39b72aqb/1

Comment: After downloading access the pdf which is downloaded, the file is corrupted. @David R

Comment: And as per the plugin it will accept the String as well. Its not compulsory to have blob type.